# unable to return array of char using a function c++

Tags: c++

It works fine now but the problem is the pointer returns strange symbols before and after the char such as <,/@ etc .. how can i solve this

```
 #include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

char* checkArray(char ch[],int start,int length,int size){

char*  sub = new char[length + 1];

if(length > size ||start > length ){
return "null";
}
else if(start + length > size){
return "null";
}
else {

for (int i=start;i < length;i++){

sub[i] = ch[i]  ;

}
return (sub);
}
}
int main(){
char data[]={'a', 'b', 'c'};
int start=1;
int length=2;

int arraysize=sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
char* res=checkArray(data,start,length,arraysize);
cout<<res;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler shout at you when you do `char  sub[] = new char[length]`?

Comment: Also, remember that C-style strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. I don't see any terminator in your code.

Comment: "null" or NULL.

Comment: we sort of need to know what the code is trying to achieve, otherwise `char* data = "abc"; std::cout << data;` better yet `std::string data = "abc"; std::cout << data;` are basically equivalent to your code, "in that they provide knowledge of size".

Comment: @Sniper Isn't it [the samed thing](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know. Haven't you heard of Christopher Null? If not, follow the link ;)

Comment: In what way are you "unable"?

Comment: it works fine to return the null,but the problem is to return the chars a , b ,c (array of characters )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic array for initializing `sub`:

```
char*  sub = new char[length];
```

Comment: thank you it works but if the start is 0 and length  is 1 it should display a but the problem is after a it displays some symbols such as < & others ?